# Is it possible to build on device from Xcode 10.1 using swift5 custom toolchain?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm running macOS 10.13.6 with Xcode 10.1 (*do not suggest to update to Mojave and Xcode 10.2*).
I've installed [latest swift toolchain](https://swift.org/download/), and modified xcode's `Swift.xcspec` file to display swift 5 option in build settings.
Everything **works** fine when I build for **simulator**. But when I changed it to device I've got one major issue during **Link** phase.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr
/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platfo
rms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -L/Users/kirow/Library/Devel
oper/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleIssue-fiylodvxeamqsidzxhdobexryiwz/Build/Products/Deb
ug-iphoneos -F/Users/kirow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleIssue-fiylodv
xeamqsidzxhdobexryiwz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/kirow/Library
/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleIssue-fiylodvxeamqsidzxhdobexryiwz/Build/Interm
ediates.noindex/SampleIssue.build/Debug-iphoneos/SampleIssue.build/Objects-normal/
arm64/SampleIssue.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Framework
s -miphoneos-version-min=12.1 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /User
s/kirow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleIssue-fiylodvxeamqsidzxhdobexryi
wz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SampleIssue.build/Debug-iphoneos/SampleIssue.build/
Objects-normal/arm64/SampleIssue_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_dedup
licate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Library/Developer/Toolchains/
swift-5.0.1-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xli
nker /Users/kirow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleIssue-fiylodvxeamqsidz
xhdobexryiwz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SampleIssue.build/Debug-iphoneos/SampleIs
sue.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SampleIssue.swiftmodule -Xlinker -dependency_info -
Xlinker /Users/kirow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleIssue-fiylodvxeamqs
idzxhdobexryiwz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SampleIssue.build/Debug-iphoneos/Sampl
eIssue.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SampleIssue_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/kirow/
Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleIssue-fiylodvxeamqsidzxhdobexryiwz/Build
/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SampleIssue.app/SampleIssue
```

```
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
```

that leads to

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Custom Swift toolchains are not really mean for real iOS devices.